# Why Angular 4 build change HTML direction?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I am trying to use Material 2 for Angular 4, I use right to left because of the language of the website I'm working on. I get some problems with the directions and Material does not work as expected because of it.

When I do `ng build --prod --aot` it change something that material 2 needs that!

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

the `dir` attribute of the HTML is what Material understands the website is right to left, but what I get in my index.html after ng build --prod --aot` is:

```
<html i18n-values="dir:textdirection;lang:language">
```

I don't know if is this Material action, or Angular compiler changes...!